# UITableViewCell cannot remove insets

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, separator

I have gone through every single solution I could find in regards to removeing the inset on the left hand side of the border. This is the code I have applied and the apple documentation has said that this is the property I should apply it to.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("voicemailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    return cell
}
```

I have no idea why this isnt working my only reasoning is that I shouldnt be applying it to the cell there but surely the `let cell` is referencing the cell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply edit this setting in storyboard.
Select your tableView -> Go to inspector and then set Content Inset to custom.
Default padding is 15 - Set it to 0

and test this in real device. It should work.

If nothing works for you try adding a view at the bottom of cell with height=1 and hide the default separator.

Comment: I have tried doing it through the inspector but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Have you tested on real devices? Simulator has this problem.

Comment: You were correct once I loaded this onto a device it worked fine